# MDX Calculated member Sum of selected members rollup

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I'm trying to write a calculated member that will roll up along a dimension based on the selected values provided on the axes.

Product -> subcategory -> category
lexus -> sedan -> car
lexus-coupe -> coupe -> car
bmw -> sedan -> car
bmw-coupe -> couple -> car
ford -> pickup -> truck
chev -> pickup -> truck
ford-suv -> suv -> truck
lincoln-nav -> suv -> truck

[Calculated measure] = [measures].[a]+[measures].[b]

suppose the user wants to see [Calculated measure] at the car level for just lexus-coupe and bmw.  How do you create a calculated measure that will roll up at the car level based on what has been selected in the dimension?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "has been selected" ? Do you have an example of your MDX request ? By the way, you can have a look to a documentation about calculated member [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.html)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - been out of town.  So the syntax of the MDX request... would be something like `SELECT [Measures].[MyMeasure] on columns, filter(descendants(product.sedan, product.category, self_and_before), <some filter criteria that removes some leaves>) on rows from mycube) .... where [measures].[MyMeasure] is defined as the tuple of (product.CurrentMember, OtherDimension.ParticularMember, measures.SomeOtherMeasure`.  Yes, i know it's silly, but the customer wants a measure field for SomeOtherMeasure/ParticularMember tuple that will pivot on other dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously written MDX to check what dimensions are being used on rows (or columns) and change the way a measure is being calculated. It is a bit messy.

This example looks to see if axis 1 (rows?) is using any Measures, and can change the calculation accordingly:

```
IIF(InStr(1, SetToStr(StrToSet("Axis(1)")), "[Measures].") = 0, blah, blah)
```

Can't remember why I did StrToSet and then SetToStr, but it worked!

You may be able to use VBA string functions like `InStr()` to examine what the user has selected on rows and columns, and fiddle with your calculated members accordingly...

Comment: It makes sense, but I am looking for the "blah" that will roll up correctly through the levels of the dimensions in Axis(1) ...